# Why is a JavaScript CSS class breaking this script?

Tags: javascript, css

Here's the script-

```
<script language=javascript>
function apply()
{
  document.form1.sub.disabled=true;
  if(document.form1.chk.checked==true)
  {
    document.form1.sub.disabled=false;
  }
  if(document.form1.chk.checked==false)
  {
    document.form1.sub.enabled=false;
  }
}
</script>
```

If I use this html it doesn't work--

```
<input class="field checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk" onClick="apply()" value="accept" />
```

However, this also doesn't work--

```
<input class="field" type="checkbox" name="chk" onClick="apply()" value="accept" />
```

But this does work--

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk" onClick="apply()" value="accept" />
```

So if the class "field" is in there it breaks the JS. Of course I can take it out, but I want to know why it doesn't work?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Sorry folks, here's the whole page. The CSS is just controlling the position of the element, it shouldn't interfere with the JS as far as I know...? -

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['referrer'])){
    //get the referrer
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']){
        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    } else {
        $referrer = "unknown";
}
//save it in a session
$_SESSION[’referrer’] = $referrer; // store session data
}

//grab campaign var from url
$campaign = $_GET['campaign'];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Beerfest Packages Sweepstakes - Blue Ridge Country</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/wufoo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/structure.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" type="text/css" />
<script language=javascript>
function apply()
{
  document.form1.sub.disabled=true;
  if(document.form1.chk.checked==true)
  {
    document.form1.sub.disabled=false;
  }
  if(document.form1.chk.checked==false)
  {
    document.form1.sub.enabled=false;
  }
}
</script>  
</head>

<body id="public">

<img id="top" src="images/top.png" alt="" />
<div id="container">

<h1><a href="">Wufoo</a></h1>

<form class="wufoo" action="insert.php" method="post" name="form1">

    <div class="info">
        <h2>Register to Win &amp; Subscribe to Blue Ridge Country</h2>
        <div>Now's your chance to not only register to win our free beerfest tickets and getaway, but also receive the #1 magazine in the Blue Ridge Mountains!</div>
    </div>

    <ul>

    <li class="section first">
        <h3>Your information</h3>
        <div>Whether you're registering to win or subscribing to the magazine (or both!) we need your info!</div>
    </li>

    <li>
    <label class="desc">Name <span class="req">*</span></label>
        <span>
        <input class="field text" size="8" value=""/>
        <label>First</label>
        </span>

        <span>
        <input class="field text" size="3" value=""/>
        <label>M.I.</label>
        </span>

        <span>
        <input class="field text" size="14" value=""/>
        <label>Last</label>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
    <label class="desc">Email <span class="req">*</span></label>
        <div>
        <input class="field text medium" type="text" name="email" maxlength="100" value="" /> 
        </div>
        <p class="instruct">Don't worry, we won't spam you, share or sell your email address!</p>
    </li>    
    <li>
    <label class="desc">Address <span class="req">*</span></label>
        <div>
        <input class="field text medium" type="text" maxlength="100" value="" /> 
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
        <input class="field text" size="15" value="" />
        <label>City</label>
        </span>

        <span>
        <input class="field text" size="2" value="" />
        <label>State</label>
        </span>

        <span>
        <input class="field text" size="5" maxlength="10" value="" />
        <label>Zip</label>
        </span>
    </li>

    <li>
    <label class="desc">Phone <span class="req">*</span></label>
        <span>
        <input class="field text" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" value=""/> - 
        <label>Area</label>
        </span>

        <span>
        <input class="field text" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" value=""/>
        <label>Phone</label>
        </span>
    </li>    

    <li class="section">
        <h3>Legal mumbo jumbo</h3>
        <div>Don't worry, you're almost done and this is the last bit we need from you!</div>
    </li>

    <li>
    <label class="desc">Official Rules <span class="req">*</span></label>
        <div>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" class="field textarea medium" readonly="readonly" style="font-size: 0.8em;">1. To enter, complete an online request by submitting this completed form. Or, send a stamped, self-addressed envelope to: "Blue Ridge Country Beerfest Promotion," Leisure Publishing, PO Box 21535, Roanoke, VA 24018, requesting an entry form. Limited to one entry per household. Entries must be received by June 30, 2009. 2. Reservation procedures to come with notification of winning. Package not available during holidays and special events. Notification of prizes will be sent to winners at the email address on the entry form. The odds of winning will depend upon the number of entries. 3. All prizes will be awarded to winners selected by random drawing from all valid entries received. Drawing will be conducted by Leisure Publishing Inc., an independent publisher, whose decisions are final on all matters relating to this sweepstakes. Winners will be notified by email to the address provided on the entry form. Only one prize to a family or household. Due to the nature of this competition, you must be 21 or older to win. Proof of age will be required prior to receiving free tickets to alcohol-related events. 4. Sweepstakes is open to all residents of the U.S. and Canada except advertisers, their employees, their advertising and promotion agencies, and the families of each. Void wherever taxed, restricted or prohibited by law. Prizes are not transferable; may not be exchanged or substituted; cannot be redeemed for cash; must be taken in their entirety; no substitutions permitted. Taxes, if any, are the responsibility of the individual winners. 5. Entry in sweepstakes constitutes permission to use winners’ names and photograph for advertising and publicity purposes, without further compensation to winners. For names of prize winners, send a stamped, self-addressed envelope to: "Blue Ridge Country Beerfest Promotion" — Winners, P.O. Box 21535, Roanoke, VA 24018.</textarea>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="section">
        <h3>Subscribe / Win!</h3>
        <div>While you don't have to subscribe to win, we hope you will!</div>
    </li>

    <li>
    <label class="desc">Sweepstakes Selection</label>
        <div class="col">
        <span><input id="choice1" name="mc" class="field radio" type="radio" value="Robots" checked="checked" />
        <label class="choice" for="choice1">Robots</label></span>

        <span><input id="choice2" name="mc" class="field radio" type="radio" value="Monkeys"/>
        <label class="choice" for="choice2">Monkeys</label></span>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
    <label class="desc">Official Rules</label>
        <div class="col">
        <span><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk" onClick="apply()" value="accept" />
        <label class="choice">I accept the terms and conditions from the "Official Rules" above.</label></span>
        </div>
    </li>    

    <li class="buttons">
        <input id="saveForm" class="btTxt" type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" />
    </li>
    </ul>

    <div style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="<?php echo $referrer; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="campaignID" value="<?php echo $campaign; ?>" />
    </div>

</form>

</div>
```

Comment: All three versions of the HTML works for me on FF3.  Some more information is required - which browser are you using?  What's the CSS?  What is the rest of your page like?

Comment: Your function makes very little sense - is enabled an extension of yours? If not, then I suggest a refactor is in order.

Comment: Not related, but is there really an enabled property for your document.form1.sub or should that read disabled=true?

Comment: @annakata...my question as well. @Marty, can you post more? The class name shouldn't change anything based on what you posted, it's not even referenced. Some much clarity is necessary.

Comment: Just posted the whole page, thanks!

Comment: Code as posted WFM, and since I still refuse to believe it's CSS related I suggest you investigate with firebug + breakpoints

Comment: I will do that...also, using FF3.5b99

Comment: problem is i'm not a JS guru :)  it's just weird that everything works if I take out "field" from the css class

Comment: ok, try removing the woofoo script

Answer (score 3):

Without waiting for your edit, I can almost guarantee that the problem lies in some other bit of JS code on your page which is changing the state to something other than you think it is. There's simply no way I can see this being related to CSS. I advise you check the DOM and walk through the method executing in firebug.

And fwiw I'll also wager that your function should be rewritten:

```
function apply()
{
  with(document.form1) { sub.disabled = !chk.checked; }
}
```